# Why is my cron job delaying its task?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have set a cron job at cpanel to automatically post something to database every midnight. [image: this is a picture to show the cron job in my cpanel.]

However, this cron job runs exactly at 7am. I have tried setting different time zones in my php.ini but it by no means affect this cron job.

Someone tell me what the problem is.

Comment: Thing is php doesn't run cron....

Comment: its the server time, nothing to do with php settings

Comment: setup your server time properly .because cron running by server not php

Comment: @jothi:  OP uses cpanel and obviously doesn't manage the server.

Comment: Are you guys really helping me? It seems stackoverflow is now a war base of who is smarter! downvoting my question without giving a solution shows how ignorant you guys are and just how less your php knowledge is. You're just here to downvote questions and answers because you simply don't understand the question! I'm off stack overflow.

Comment: @stackoverflowfan please abuse the free help some more, see how far that gets you.

Comment: @Dagon, i wish you were here to help.

Comment: whats wrong with  @JuliePelletier's answer?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Go to the command prompt and type:
date

Still at the command prompt type:
php -r "echo date('D M j H:i:s T Y');"

Have a look at the difference between server time and PHP time

Kev

Comment: please stop posting answers until you understand how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @KevinWaterson:  Your answer does not address the real issue of the job running at the wrong time and also doesn't take into account that OP probably doesn't even have shell access.

Comment: @KevinWaterson, where do i go from there? the difference is one hour. The server time is one hour behind.

Comment: Change your server time to your locale.

Comment: @KevinWaterson This is not not answer of question and i don't know why you accepted as best answer, what this answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply change the `hour` to run it for `17`, then it will run at midnight your time.

Explanation:  Since your current job scheduled for midnight runs at 7AM (your local time), you want it to run 7 hours earlier.  So the server's time will be 5PM (17 on a 24 hour clock) when it's midnight for you.

Comment: please explain how this works. If I test it, I will have to wait another day to see if it works. some little explanation will build the confidence in trying this.

Comment: @stackoverflowfan:  I added an explanation.

Comment: The script uses date to choose data from a table, so that it can update another table. it checks the date, goes to the db and takes content that has that date. that simply can't work.

Comment: @stackoverflowfan again, the date php uses, and the date the server uses, and the date mySQL uses, may all be different

Comment: @Dagon, go get some sleep.

Comment: @stackoverflowfan but its only 5pm.

Answer (score 0):

Frist of all php.ini can not set server timezone and crontab run by server time so you have to change server time according to your time zone and sync your domain to that time zone.

Now create cron in cpanel as below

```
0   7   *   *   *   your command /location of file
```

Here we will use 7 for 7AM, i hope this will help you.

**Or**

You can set time as fit to your time zone, convert your timezone according to server time zone and set time **(As i have set 7)**, after that it will sure run according to you.